# Not able to build xamarin iOS application in Visual studio for Mac version 8.1.3

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am facing some issues in building my Xamarin iOS application. When I try to build, I get an error as :

> Can't resolve the reference 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder::GetMember(Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpBinderFlags,System.String,System.Type,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1)', referenced from the method 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder Microsoft.Identity.Json.Utilities.DynamicUtils/BinderWrapper::GetMember(System.String,System.Type)' in 'Microsoft.CSharp, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I tried finding a reference to Microsoft.Csharp 2.0.5.0 but it seems like there is no reference to this binary.

Also, I am able to build and deploy Android and UWP apps without any issue.

It will be great if somebody can help.

Comment: It's a shot in the dark but are you using the `dynamic` keyword? If so can you remove this and try to deploy again. Not a solution ofcourse but it might help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @ywwy When I click the deploy button, it starts doing certain stuff and starts building the project and then it ends up with this error. Adding to that, I am getting  this error only in case of iOS and not in Android and UWP

Comment: @saurabh bohra  Are you able to build the IOS app separately ?   You might want to edit your question and add the comment information to your question.

Comment: @ywwy No, the iOS application gives the same error when I try to build the application. I have made certain edits to my questions to be more accurate.

Comment: @saurabh bohra  your project probably cannot find the reference to System.Dynamic.Runtime .   Did you add/use it ? remove it ?  At what moment did this error appear ?

Comment: @saurabh bohra   Check your "system.core"  Reference.  Has it a yellow triangle next to it ?

Comment: @ywwy No, system.core doesn't have any yellow triangle and also System.Dynamic.Runtime is not referenced or used in the project. But still, I added its reference just to make sure that if this was the cause. But there was no benefit and the same error is received.

Comment: @saurabh bohra Last thing I am thinking of. I am surprised to see CSharp 2.0 in the error message.  Especially because you are using a recent Visual studio for Mac.  Maybe check the Csharp version that is used.   Goto the project properties, Build tab, Advanced button.  Take the more recent one.